# Using an alternative scripting language in a Qt HTML5 Application

Tags: c++, ruby, html, qt

I am creating and HTML5 Application using the Qt Framework.  I am using QtWebkit to display my HTML.  I know QtWebkit has the `addToJavascriptObject` capability, but I don't like javascript that much and I would rather do the scripting with some other language like Ruby, just like TideSDK has it.

The application will be cross-platform and also on a mobile platform.

How would this be possible? Is there a way to get the same effect as `addToJavascriptObject` but with Ruby, for instance?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unless by rewriting a large portion of QtWebkit itself. It is tied with Javascript very closely.

Comment: @SirDarius: +1, although I +1'd the question, too because I feel some sympathy. I do not like javascript either, and I would prefer an OOP scripting language, like python...

Comment: @LaszloPapp yes, I +1 your +1's although there might be an escape route, for example by using a [insert your favorite language]-to-JS converter, or something like Coffeescript that is at least closer to Ruby :)

Comment: @SirDarius: true, adapter is indeed a (not-so-)good idea. Updated my answer respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would this be possible?

No.

> Is there a way to get the same effect as addToJavascriptObject but with Ruby, for instance?

No.

The Qt framework is heavily attached to javascript when it comes to scripting; like it or not.

That being said, I have some sympathy towards your request. I dislike javascript as well because I prefer OOP programming. I would like to see e.g. python, but this is currently not possible, and definitely not a targetted direction in the Qt Project.

You may be able to use some adapter that converts your code in the preferred language to javascript that Qt accepts, but then you are entirely on your own. I would not recommend this for several reasons.

Once you encounter an issue with the interpration, you would need to work it around manually, potentially including the hacking of your disliked javascript.

Moreover, Qt may decide to have a somewhat customized javascript version at any single point in which case the interpreter would become broken.

I understand your personal preference, but I would suggest to get used to it; it is not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not possible directly, you might have some success by using for instance Ruby as main language, and an intermediary compilation step to Javascript, using a tool such as http://opalrb.org/.

I don't really know how good it can be, and if the generated code is efficient. But at any rate, if maintainability is your primary concern, you should have a look.